# Hibernate Criteria on Referenced table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a function that merges two tables, each of these tables has a column that I want to filter.

```
@Entity
public class Contacts {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne //reference user_id = id
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne //reference people_id = id
    private People people;
    //getters and setters
}


@Entity
public class User {
   private int id;
   private int name;
   private Enterprise enterprise;
   //getters and setters
}



@Entity
public class People {
   private int id;
   private int name;
   //..others fields
   private Enterprise enterprise;
   //getters and setters
}
```

I need to list all "Contacts" where my enterprise id = 1. On a simple select (SQLServer), it will be:

```
 SELECT c.* FROM CONTACTS c
  INNER JOIN User u ON u.id = c.user_id
  INNER JOIN People p on p.id = p.people_id
  WHERE u.empresa_id = 1
```

I can't figure out how to do it with Criteria API, I already tried the follow code, but I keep receiving an error.

```
//code..public List<Obj> list(int id) {
   Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Contacts.class);
   crit.add(Restrictions.eq(user.enterprise.id, id)); //it doesn't work!
   crit.list();
}
```

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: user.enterprise.id of: sys.com.model.Contacts

Comment: use this line:-- crit.add(Restrictions.eq("people.enterprise.id",1)) where 1 is enterpriseId

Comment: Just updated the topic.

Comment: use user.enterprise.id as "user.enterprise.id".....hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

here i am writing code for sample using criteria.

```
public List<Student_document> getUserById(int id) {
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(
                Student_document.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user_document.user_Id", id));
        return criteria.list();
    }
```

Comment: Same...the problem is, I don't have referenced the "user_id" in my class, I just extend the other class with a @ManyToOne relation.

I Will update the references on the topic.